# How to enumerate UMS scheduler threads using GetUmsSystemThreadInformation?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to use GetUmsSystemThreadInformation to enumerate UMS scheduler threads but I can't make it work the way it's intended.

This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "UMSEnum.h"

void EnumerateThreads(DWORD tid) {
    // Create a snapshot of all processes
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);

    if (hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cerr << "[-] Error creating snapshot: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Initialize the THREADENTRY32 structure
    THREADENTRY32 threadEntry;
    threadEntry.dwSize = sizeof(THREADENTRY32);

    // Retrieve information about the first thread
    if (Thread32First(hSnapshot, &threadEntry)) {
        do {
            // Display information about each thread
            // std::cout << "[.] Thread ID: " << threadEntry.th32ThreadID << std::endl;

            // Get the thread handle using the thread ID
            if (threadEntry.th32ThreadID != tid && tid != 0)
                continue;

            HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, threadEntry.th32ThreadID);

            if (hThread != NULL) {
                UMS_SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION tInfo;
                tInfo.UmsVersion = UMS_VERSION;
                tInfo.IsUmsSchedulerThread = 1;
                tInfo.IsUmsWorkerThread = 0;
                // Perform actions on the thread handle if needed
                BOOL found = GetUmsSystemThreadInformation(hThread, &tInfo);
                if ( found && GetLastError() != ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    std::cout << "[.] "
                        << threadEntry.th32OwnerProcessID
                        << "[" << threadEntry.th32ThreadID << "]"
                        << "[" << tInfo.IsUmsSchedulerThread << "]"
                        << "[" << tInfo.IsUmsWorkerThread << "]"
                        << "[" << tInfo.ThreadUmsFlags << "]"
                        << std::endl;
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "[-] GetUmsSystemThreadInformation failed - " << threadEntry.th32ThreadID << " - " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
                }
                // Close the thread handle
                CloseHandle(hThread);
            }
            //else {
            //    std::cerr << "Error opening thread: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            //}

        } while (Thread32Next(hSnapshot, &threadEntry));
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "[-] Error getting thread information: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    // Close the thread snapshot handle
    CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    EnumerateThreads(atol(argv[1]));
    return 0;
}
```

It may seem right, at least to me, but this code will list every thread id in the system, not only the UMS scheduler ones as it was suppose to. Also, GetUmsSystemThreadInformation always returns true.

The following is a test application I am using to create a UMS Scheduler Thread.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

PUMS_COMPLETION_LIST g_CompletionList;

RTL_UMS_SCHEDULER_ENTRY_POINT RtlUmsSchedulerEntryPoint;

void RtlUmsSchedulerEntryPoint(
    RTL_UMS_SCHEDULER_REASON Reason,
    ULONG_PTR ActivationPayload,
    PVOID SchedulerParam
)
{
    std::cout << "[+] It works - " << GetCurrentThreadId() << std::endl;
    switch (Reason)
    {
    case UmsSchedulerStartup:
        std::cout << "[+] UmsSchedulerStartup" << std::endl;
        break;
    case UmsSchedulerThreadBlocked:
        std::cout << "[+] UmsSchedulerThreadBlocked" << std::endl;
        break;
    case UmsSchedulerThreadYield:
        std::cout << "[+] UmsSchedulerThreadYield" << std::endl;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI SchedulerThreadProc(LPVOID lpThreadParameter)
{
    UMS_SCHEDULER_STARTUP_INFO umsStartupInfo;
    umsStartupInfo.UmsVersion = UMS_VERSION;
    umsStartupInfo.SchedulerParam = nullptr;
    umsStartupInfo.SchedulerProc = RtlUmsSchedulerEntryPoint;
    umsStartupInfo.CompletionList = g_CompletionList;
    if (!EnterUmsSchedulingMode(&umsStartupInfo))
    {
        std::cerr << "[-] EnterUmsSchedulingMode failed - " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    Sleep(INFINITE);

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    UMS_SCHEDULER_STARTUP_INFO startupInfo;
    if (!CreateUmsCompletionList(&g_CompletionList)) {
        std::cerr << "[-] CreateUmsCompletionList failed - " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, SchedulerThreadProc, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (hThread == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "[-] CreateThread failed - " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    int foo;
    std::cin >> foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an example of running both:

[image]

I think I don't know how to properly set the SystemThreadInfo.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: in any case *As of Windows 11, user-mode scheduling is not supported. All calls fail with the error ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED.*

Comment: I am running a Windows 10 system.

Comment: and so what ? exist sense use this at all ? your code anyway wrong. use `UMS_SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION tInfo{UMS_VERSION};` as init and you not check `IsUmsSchedulerThread` and `IsUmsWorkerThread`- which it values ? *If both IsUmsSchedulerThread and IsUmsWorkerThread are clear, the structure specifies a non-UMS thread.*

Comment: Looks like the call always returns true in Windows 10, never setting the last error to ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED, despite how the UMS_SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION  struct is initialized.

Comment: Are you read and understand my comment or documentation of api ( from where i copy paste it ) ? You not check result of api call, so what you want ?

Comment: I did read the docs. I am now zeroing out the whole struct and setting IsUmsSchedulerThread only. The function still always returns true and a meaningful API error is never set.  After the call both IsUmsSchedulerThread and IsUmsWorkerThread are also all set to zero, even targeting a thread that successfully called EnterUmsSchedulingMode and had UmsSchedulerStartup confirmed.

It sounds like you are able to make GetUmsSystemThreadInformation work as expected. A working sample would be helpful.

Comment: you need check IsUmsSchedulerThread and IsUmsWorkerThread **after** GetUmsSystemThreadInformation return true. but you not do this (in code which you show). current code is senseless

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256282/discussion-between-bananabr-and-rbmm).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Warning
>     
> As of Windows 11, user-mode scheduling is not supported. 
> All calls fail with the error ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED.
> ```

from current msdn documentation:

> [in, out] *SystemThreadInfo*
>
> A pointer to an initialized `UMS_SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION` structure
> that specifies the kind of thread for the query.

and

> Returns `TRUE` if the specified thread matches the kind of thread
> specified by the *SystemThreadInfo* parameter. Otherwise, the function
> returns `FALSE`.

however this is very strange and unlogical api design. also in this case *SystemThreadInfo* will be only **in** parameter, but why it marked as `_Inout_` in api declaration ? and *[in, out]* in documentation ?

Otherwise, the function returns `FALSE` - but with which error ? how to distinguish an error - say, an incorrect parameter, an incorrect stream descriptor, no access rights to a *hThread* - from an "error" - the wrong type of thread ? must be documented error value, returned by `GetLastError()` in this case.

the logical and native design will be next - the *IsUmsSchedulerThread* and *IsUmsWorkerThread* must be **out** parameters. api must return true, if `hThread` correct thread handle with `THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION` access right.
and we must check *IsUmsSchedulerThread* and *IsUmsWorkerThread* after api return, instead set it before api call.

let look for source code of `GetUmsSystemThreadInformation`

```
BOOL
WINAPI
GetUmsSystemThreadInformation(
    _In_ HANDLE ThreadHandle,
    _Inout_ PUMS_SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION SystemThreadInfo
    )
{
    if (UMS_VERSION != SystemThreadInfo->UmsVersion) return STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    THREAD_UMS_INFORMATION tui = { UmsInformationCommandQuery };
    ULONG rcb;
    NTSTATUS status = NtQueryInformationThread(hThread, ThreadUmsInformation, &tui, sizeof(tui), &rcb);
    if (0 > status)
    {
      RtlSetLastWin32Error(RtlNtStatusToDosError(status));
      return FALSE;
    }
  
    SystemThreadInfo->ThreadUmsFlags = tui.Flags;
    return TRUE;
}
```

from it clear visible that `IsUmsSchedulerThread` and `IsUmsWorkerThread` is **ignored** as input and set as **output only**, after api call

so correct code for check thread must be next:

```
void CheckUmsThread(HANDLE hThread, ULONG pid, ULONG tid)
{
    UMS_SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION SystemThreadInfo { UMS_VERSION };

    if (GetUmsSystemThreadInformation(hThread, &SystemThreadInfo))
    {
        if (SystemThreadInfo.ThreadUmsFlags && SystemThreadInfo.ThreadUmsFlags)
        {
            __debugbreak();
        }

        PCSTR pcsz = 0;

        if (SystemThreadInfo.IsUmsSchedulerThread)
        {
            pcsz = "Scheduler";
        }
        else if (SystemThreadInfo.IsUmsWorkerThread)
        {
            pcsz = "Worker";
        }

        if (pcsz)
        {
            DbgPrint("%x.%x: Ums%sThread\n", pid, tid, pcsz);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        GetLastError();
        RtlGetLastNtStatus();
    }
}
```

the complete code can be next:

```
NTSTATUS status;
ULONG cb = 0x10000;
do 
{
    status = STATUS_NO_MEMORY;
    if (PVOID buf = LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, cb += 0x1000))
    {
        if (0 <= (status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buf, cb, &cb)))
        {
            union {
                ULONG_PTR up;
                SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION* pspi;
                PVOID pv;
            };

            pv = buf;
            ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;
            OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa) };
            do 
            {
                up += NextEntryOffset;

                if (ULONG NumberOfThreads = pspi->NumberOfThreads)
                {
                    SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION* Thread = (SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION*)pspi->Threads;
                    do 
                    {
                        HANDLE hThread;
                        if (0 <= NtOpenThread(&hThread, THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, &oa, &Thread->ClientId))
                        {
                            CheckUmsThread(hThread, 
                                (ULONG)(ULONG_PTR)Thread->ClientId.UniqueProcess, 
                                (ULONG)(ULONG_PTR)Thread->ClientId.UniqueThread);

                            NtClose(hThread);
                        }

                    } while (Thread++, --NumberOfThreads);
                }
            } while (NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset);
        }

        LocalFree(buf);
    }

} while (STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH == status);
```

Comment: Where did you get the source code for GetUmsSystemThreadInformation??

Comment: @bananabr from debugger